# Trying to redirect a page if the URL contains a word i'm banning from my website

Tags: php, wordpress, search, redirect, search-engine

I have been given a code to redirect a page if people try using my search form in Wordpress to search for vulgar or adult words.

The reason I am doing this is because Google can ban people from Adsense even for having just rude words in any URL, even those generated by search functions.

This is the message I got from Google:

"Ad serving has been disabled to: examplesite.com

Example page where violation occurred: http://examplesite.com/?s=somekeyword+tv+sex"

I have appealed but I need to redirect access to any further such searches on my website as searches are generating URL's that Google are then indexing.

I have tried this script I have been given but inserting it in to my Wordpress search.php but I am getting this error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /home/name/public_html/sitename.com/wp-content/themes/heatmap-adsense-theme/search.php on line 83

Line 83 refers to the following code: if($pageURL;

The full code is below:

```
    <?php
   function curPageURL() {
   $pageURL = 'http';
   if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
   $pageURL .= "://";
   if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
   $pageURL .= 

   $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
     } else {
      $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
     }
     if($pageURL;
     $string = "/sex/";

     if (preg_match_all($string, $pageURL, &$matches)) {
          header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); /* Redirect browser */
      }
   }
   ?>
```

The code looks pretty complete but please could somebody help me resolve that error and any after.

Thanks in advance.

PS: Sorry if this is message is formatted badly. Doing my best but can not see any preview button.

Comment: What don't you understand about the error message, exactly?

Comment: It should be if($pageURL)  and not if($pageURL;

Comment: thanks. why do people keep marking down my questions though?

Comment: @GaryCarlyleCook Because your question doesn't show any research.  You have an elementary error in there that you should have recognized.

Comment: @GaryCarlyleCook it seems like everyone is starting to immediately vote down questions and answers for no good reason now adays.  Starting to lower the value of the site IMHO.

Comment: Lack of research? It was an emergency and I am new to coding. Are newbies not allowed here or something. Not everybody is an expert in everything but everybody is an expert in something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked best for me.

```
<?php $bad_words = array('some','bad','words','sex'); foreach($bad_words as $bad_word){ if(stristr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], $bad_word) !== false) { echo "Have a nice weekend!"; } else { echo "Have a nice day!"; } } ?>
```

Answer (score 9):

Im pretty sure you can tell google not to index the page if you use a 404 or a 410 Gone header, so when a specific keyword search term is used pop that extra header in there, or just redirect to a warning page.

If you want to do it with PHP and no regex:

```
<?php 
$bad_words = array('some','bad','words','sex');

foreach($bad_words as $bad_word){
    if(stristr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], $bad_word) !== false) {
        exit(header("Location: http://www.example.com/"));
        //exit(header("HTTP/1.0 410 Gone"));
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This worked the best for my requirements. Cheers. :)

<?php 
$bad_words = array('some','bad','words','sex');

foreach($bad_words as $bad_word){
    if(stristr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], $bad_word) !== false)  
  {
  echo "Have a nice weekend!";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Have a nice day!";
  }
}
?>

Comment: Ok, Dont forget to upvote or accept if you found it somwhat useful ;p

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a redirect via server-configuration:

```
#.htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (place|bad|words|here) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/? [R=302,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The above script seems to have an error in it:

```
if($pageURL;
 $string = "/sex/";
```

This should be removed as the following if statement is doing a regular expression match.